# Variables not working inside file_get_contents php

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Im trying to pull content from google maps API.
But when I concatenate a variable inside the URL it doesn't work 
If I just use the plan text it works.
What am i doing wrong here?

Not working:

```
$post_location = "lagos";
$url_loc = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='. $post_location .'&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDXX_Y0-7b1XM2';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url_loc), true);

var_dump($obj); //outputs null
```

But this works:

```
$url_loc = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=lagos&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDXX_Y0-7b1XM2';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url_loc), true);

var_dump($obj); //outputs all results
```

Why isnt the first option working?

Full code i'm working with

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="surl" value="/storefront/output.json">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){  

  $url = $_POST['surl'];
  $string = file_get_contents($url);
  $json_a = json_decode($string, true);
  $post_id = 243;

  foreach ($json_a as $person_name => $person_a) {

        $post_location =  $person_a['location'];
        $url_loc = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$post_location.'&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDXX_Y0-7b1XM2';
        $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url_loc), true);
        var_dump($obj); // outputs null

        foreach ($obj as $key ) {     

                $lat = $key[0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
                $lng = $key[0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];


                $full_address = $key[0]['formatted_address'];

                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'prod-lat', sanitize_text_field( $lat )); 
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'prod-lng', sanitize_text_field( $lng )); 



            break;

        } 
  }

}
```

Comment: have you tryed: `$url_loc = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$post_location&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDXX_Y0-7b1XM2";`

Comment: @AlvaroAlves why would that make a difference?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($post_location, $url_loc);` before your `file_get_contents()` call?

Comment: [The string concatenation is not the problem](https://ideone.com/UPLmgH). You should check the rest of your code.

Comment: Maybe if you are using more concatenations, this could be result in an inesperate behavior. This happen to me once.

Comment: Both examples as you have presented them here "work". You have other issues going on not conveyed to us.

Comment: @IncredibleHat if thats the case why does the second one work and not the first. What else could be wrong?

Comment: @IncredibleHat i posted the full code

Comment: `$person_a['location']` _could_ be an invalid value.

Comment: @waterloomatt its not when i var dump it gives me the correct value

Comment: can you echo out $url_loc .. is there anything odd in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thing you're passing illegal characters to URL string. If you want to pass your $post_location variable to URL use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function:

```
$post_location = "some address here";
$url_loc = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='. 
urlencode($post_location) .'&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDXX_Y0-7b1XM2';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url_loc), true);
```

Without urlencode you'll get warning: `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /var/www/public_html/index.php on line 7` - look into your log files or display all PHP errors.

Comment: I'm glad I could help